# Docker-compose could not translate host name "postgres"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm fairly new to Docker.
When I run `docker-compose up`, I would get the following error.

```
PG::ConnectionBad
could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve
```

In the log, it says the following

```
postgres_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
postgres_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "SQL_ASCII".
postgres_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
postgres_1   | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
postgres_1   | the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
postgres_1   | with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

This is my docker-compose setup.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: "bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - "3020:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgresql-data:
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM ruby:2.3.7-alpine

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV RAILS_ENV=development

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual=builders \
      alpine-sdk build-base linux-headers ruby-dev zlib-dev postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      libc6-compat libc-dev zlib ruby-json tzdata yaml less curl postgresql
RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app
```

```
# database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: postgres
  username: postgres
  password: 
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  template: template0
  database: todo_development
```

What am I doing wrong here??

If I change `host` from `postgres` to `localhost` in my `database.yml`, I get the following error.

```
Connection refused Is the server running on host “localhost” (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: The PostgreSQL error is clear, isn't it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Albe I guess the error is clear but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You need an empty directory to run `initdb` in. Empty the volume.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you!! I did a similar thing with my containers. and That worked!!